# com.iceteck.silicompressorr.provider.GenericFileProvider doesn't found and crash app

Tags: android, android-studio

When I install app on the device with the android 4.4 app crashed and I get this error in the logcat.
But app installs and correctly work on the above android.
How can I fix this error
I also add the below code on the manifiests.xml and didn't get any result

```
<provider
    android:name="com.iceteck.silicompressorr.provider.GenericFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.silli.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    tools:replace="android:authorities">
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.iceteck.silicompressorr.provider.GenericFileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.iceteck.silicompressorr.provider.GenericFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.mspars.azmoun-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.mspars.azmoun-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4605)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.iceteck.silicompressorr.provider.GenericFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.mspars.azmoun-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.mspars.azmoun-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5116)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have not selected the lowest Android version when you are creating a new project.
if this is the problem try this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5lRTCaqhII&ab_channel=CodeDocu_com